# Can I install Ubuntu on the same hard drive I booted with?

Tags: installation, hard-drive, external-hdd

I booted Ubuntu using an external hard drive. Is it possible to install it on the same hard-drive without unplugging or turning it off? I only have one working USB port and the internal PC hard-drive is dead.

Comment: You can only do so if you are installing it to a partition other than that you are booting it from, even on the same disk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to partion your hardrive first. Then install the live environment on one half. When you boot into the installer you can now install on the other half.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use **GParted** to partition your harddisk(you can shrink your partition without losing your data and then make another partition).

When you have 2 partition then you can install Ubuntu on the other partition even when you are booting from the first.