# Install Ubuntu 12.04.05 from Hard Drive: Installation Type screen blank, dmraid not helpful

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, dmraid

### Computer Setup and Desired Outcome

I have a Dell Dimension 8200 running Windows XP Home Edition on a 80GB Maxtor 6L080L4 hard drive (not sure if this matters) with Intel Pentium 4 (2.00GHz) and 512MB RAM (4x 128MB sticks). I want to replace OS with Ubuntu (don't care what version as long as it works with my computer specs) and there is nothing on this computer that I want to keep (looking to do a clean install). I am not looking to do a dual-boot or run Ubuntu alongside Windows.

### Steps Towards Install

I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso from the Alternative download section for Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS onto my good laptop (Lenovo W520).  I copied it to a USB and copied it over to my Dell Dimension 8200 desktop computer.  I then used UNetbootin (though I can’t find the link where it suggested doing this as in trying to find that link to day, I saw that it is not recommended for the 16.04 version).  I opened UNetbootin and chose my hard drive as the location and the iso file to process.

I thought this was the easiest way because I only have a CD-ROM drive which 12.04 won’t fit on (file size is too large) and I didn’t want to try to boot from a USB (I do have a 3.5” floppy drive though!).

After unpackaging (not sure if that is the correct terminology) the iso onto the hard drive through UNetbootin, I restarted the computer.  Upon start up, I am given a warning that my system battery is low (hopefully this isn't part of the problem) and am prompted to press F1 to continue (the other option is F2 to go to the setup utility).  The next screen allows me to select between two options, 1) my Windows XP, or 2) UNetbootin.  I choose UNetbootin.

When I choose UNetbootin, the screen goes black then comes back with a countdown timer telling me to press ‘Esc’to go to the main menu.  When I press ‘Esc’ I get a screen that allows me to choose different options (e.g. Try Ubuntu without installing, Install Ubuntu, Check disc for defects, etc.).  When I choose the install option I get the screen prompting me for my language choice, I click continue, and the next screen states that for best results I should have 4.6 GB available drive space that I’m connected to the internet.  I click continue and enter in my router’s password so that I get connected to the internet.  I click the button which says Connect which then turns to Continue after the internet seemingly gets connected (I don’t know how to tell or if it’s even important right now). I then get to the Installation Type screen where my partition table is empty (only the headers are listed such as Device, Type, Mount point, Format?, etc. and the buttons below the table are non-functional).

### What I've Done to Problem-Solve

In writing this I have a long list of what seems to be similar questions; however, it seems like none of them pertain to me or work for me.  Below are two posts (which also link other posts) that seem to have similar issues as me, but their solutions are not working as I implement them.

I've read through this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170204/ubuntu-12-04-install-problems-installation-type-screen-no-options?lq=1) on askubuntu and these are my notes on it

1. Select /dev/sda from dropdown -> that is my only option (the partition table is blank, the buttons such as New Partition Table..., Add..., Change... all seem to be frozen/non-responsive so I click Install now and I get a warning dialog with the title "No root file system" with the body stating "No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.")
2. Run the Check Disk for Defects -> ran it and no defects were found
3. Turn off mSSD Cache in BIOS -> no option exists for me (the BIOS screen does say something about Level 2 Cache: 512 KB Integrated and the BIOS version is A05)
4. Run `sudo apt-get install mdadm` from terminal in LiveCD mode -> from the UNetbootin menu I'm able to select Try Ubuntu without installing and I'm able to type this into the terminal.  These are my results:

`Errorswere encountered while processing:`

`initramfs-tools`

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I also looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190689/only-sdb-shows-up-when-installing-12-04-on-a-new-dell-inspiron-14z) post as well and have done what they recommend.

1. Type `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` in the terminal -> the reply to this is `no raid disks and with names: "/dev/sda"`

### Solution?

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?  Is it not a RAID issue and something else (obviously user error here)!

I went into GParted and the table has two rows.  The first says /dev/sda1 with a NTFS file system, a /cdrom mount point, 74.54 GiB with 50 used and is flagged as boot.  The second row says it's unallocated with unallocated file system and is 13MiB.  I thought [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191499/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-the-same-hard-drive-i-booted-with) post might be suggesting what I should do; however, I am unable to do anything in GParted because it says I have on active partition and I can't unmount it or resize it!

I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or missing! I'm so confused!

Answer (score 0):

### What Didn't Work

I read that updating the bios would maybe "unlock" the option to boot from USB.  I was able to obtain an updated bios for my computer (A05 to A09) and I still had a floppy drive that worked so that I could update the bios (though the floppy drive was so dusty it stopped working, but I randomly kept a floppy cleaner disk around, but the solvent had evaporated so I just used rubbing alcohol, and thankfully it worked)!  Sadly, updating the bios did not "unlock" a "boot from USB" option.

### Realization Phase

I finally realized that my error was that UNetbootin installed the Ubuntu files on my C: drive which was in use even though I booted up through Ubuntu.  From what I can tell, instead of using UNetbootin to process the .iso file onto a USB, I used it to place it on my hard drive.  Upon restart, I was able to choose between Windows XP or Ubuntu; however, the Ubuntu was running off of the C: drive which is what I was trying to install Ubuntu onto.  This realization came from watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2t33xD4wI4) on an Ubuntu installation with a scratch drive.  In summary, the user makes a partition that is empty that they'll use during the installation process as the swap drive.

### My Bad: Events Leading to a New Starting Point

Unfortunately, I realized this after I had tried to install Ubuntu and instead of pressing the buttons on the error boxes that popped up, I was able to push forward fast enough that I think Ubuntu was actually starting to install, even though my partition table was empty and the installation was not going as illustrated in several videos.  Upon restart I was given the blinky underscore mark in the upper-left corner!  I couldn't start any OS.  I could go into the bios and that was it.

This forced me to pull out the Windows XP CD and following directions online, I did not choose the repair option upon start-up but rather continued.  When it showed me my drives, the C: drive was listed as something other than Windows XP (I forget what it said, but apparently it should've said Windows XP).  This gave me the opportunity to format my drives and re-partition them.  I made a C: partition for Windows, and another partition for my future Ubuntu install.  I went through the Windows installation process and once that was complete I was ready to move towards my solution.

### Problem Statement Recap

I have a Dell 8200 Dimension (purchased in 2002) with only a floppy and CD drive (thus ruling out installing from DVD) that I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04.

### What Worked for Me

I downloaded Rufus and used that to process the .iso file onto a 1GB USB drive with a FAT file system (I read that one should use a smaller USB drive...something that the computer would've seen when it was relatively new...and to format in as a file system that was common when the computer was relatively new).  With the 8200 booted in Windows XP Home Edition, I plugged the USB with the Ubuntu installer into a USB port.  I was able to open up the USB Drive and double click on wubi.exe.  After selecting "Demo and full installtion",
[image]

I then chose the "Help me to boot from CD"

[image]

I was then able to restart and upon restarting, I was given a choice again to choose either Windows XP or Ubuntu.  After choosing Ubuntu, I was able to continue with the installation process as normal. I ended performing the installation so that it is along side my Windows XP.